# Powershell inputting data into a website - property value cannot be found on a GetElementByName

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below code to interact with a html website at work, The first part to log in works however when i try and run the part

```
($ie.document.getElementsByName("textSearch") | select -first 1).value = "12345";
```

I get the following error

> **The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.**
>
> At *C:\Users\lawsod03\desktop\powershell\DCS-remove.ps1:23 char:1*
>
> + ($ie.document.getElementsByName("businessArea") |select -first 1).value = "MCS_C ...
>
> +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

This is the input field I am currently trying to add a value to

```
<td class="td_prompt">
    <input name="textSearch" value="">&nbsp;by
</td>
```

The PowerShell script is below:

```
cls
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$loginUrl = "www.website.com/login";
$MainCSA = "www.website.com/usersearch";
$iterator = 1;

#initialize browser
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($loginUrl);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; } #wait for browser idle

#login
($ie.document.getElementsByName("username") |select -first 1).value = $username;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("password") |select -first 1).value = $password;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("submit") |select -first 1).click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle

#navigate to maintain CSA
$ie.navigate($MainCSA);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle
($ie.document.getElementsByName("textSearch") |select -first 1).value = "12345";
```

I've searched online for a solution however i can't seem to find one that has pointed me in the right direction.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `select -f 1` change your format to do a coerced de-reference like this (*I've also simplified your code*):

```
function getEl ($ie, $name) {return @($ie.document.getElementsByName($name))[0]}
(getEl $ie 'username').value = $username
(getEl $ie 'password').value = $password
(getEl $ie 'submit').click()
```

This is because *`getElementsByName()`* returns a list of elements (*though not in a traditional array, thus the `@()` cast converts it to PowerShell array, and then you can de-reference like a normal array*).

Does that help?

Comment: Hi @AP , Thanks for the response The password part with loging in works and finds the elements however it is after that part when the code navigates to www.website.com/usersearch when trying to get element by name there i get the error I think i've used youre code correctly however i am VERY new to powershell please can you check, I used function getEl ($ie, $name) {return @($ie.document.getElementsByName($name))[0]} (getEl 'textSearch').value = "12345"

Comment: Just fixed my answer, forgot to include `$ie` variable when calling `getEl()`

Comment: sorry didn't see your response. it works for the login part however it does not work for the "textSearch" box i get the below error

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\lawsod03\desktop\powershell\DCS-remove2.ps1:15 char:39
+ function getEl ($ie, $name) {return @($ie.document.getElementsByName($name))[0]}
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\lawsod03\desktop\powershell\DCS-remove2.ps1:24 char:1
+ (getEl $ie 'textSearch').value = $username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: That means your browser cannot find an element by the name of **`textSearch`**. Verify the page it's on is correct at that step. (use `$ie.visible=1` to show the browser)

Comment: thank you for the continued help. i added it to the code ie.navigate($MainCSA);
$ie.visible=1
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle
(getEl $ie 'textSearch').value = $username

However i still get the error 'value' property cannot be found on this object

Comment: Could you either share this `link`, or paste the output of what you get if you just run: `(getEl $ie 'textSearch')`, or both

Comment: sadly its an internal site so im unable to share the link. When i run just (getEL $ie 'textSearch') i don't get any error. so the fault seems to be with the .value part which this element is an input so im not sure. the only thing i can think of is the form seems to be a java script form unlike the log in which is just a standard HTML form, the submit button is <a href="javascript:searchSubmit();">Search</a> could this be what is causing my issue?

Comment: Right, but do you actually get an element back when you run `(getEl $ie 'textSearch')`? If not then there is no element on that page with that name.

Comment: Based on your code you just pasted, the `<a>` tag has **no `name` attribute**. Thus the best you can do in that case is run this: `$Head = @($IE.document.getElementsByTagName("head"))[0];$Script = $IE.document.IHTMLDocument2_createElement('script');$Script.text = "searchSubmit()";$Head.appendChild($script) > $Null`

Comment: ^^ Will run the function `searchSubmit()` on your page

Comment: if i run (getEl $ie 'textSearch') i do not get any error back.

Comment: If i run $Head = @($IE.document.getElementsByTagName("head"))[0];$Script = $IE.document.IHTMLDocument2_createElement('script');$Script.‌​text = "searchSubmit()";$Head.appendChild($script) > $Null i get the error

Comment: At C:\Users\lawsod03\desktop\powershell\DCS-remove2.ps1:28 char:127
+ ... ript');$Script.??text = "searchSubmit";$Head.appendChild($script) > $Null
+                    ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName

Comment: Why do you have `??text`